# How to hide second axis in nvd3 line chart

Tags: nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 chart library to display reports in our application.I have used Line with view finder type of chart from nvd3 chart library.In line chart,we have found second axis(X and Y) which is used for filter purpose.Can you please tell me how to hide second axis??

[image: as found in the below image]

Comment: There's no option for this. You could however remove it manually by selecting the respective element and removing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I guess what you want to implement seems to be a [simple line chart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/line.html), you can use that as given in the example instead of the [Line with View Axis](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html).

Let me know if I have understood your problem wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for that, but you may archive that by do some hacking of `src/models/lineWithFocusChart.js`.

```
comment out the following lines (I suppose you're using the newest version of nvd3 1.1.10 beta)

L300-303

    g.select('.nv-context .nv-x.nv-axis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + y2.range()[0] + ')');
    d3.transition(g.select('.nv-context .nv-x.nv-axis'))
          .call(x2Axis);

L311-315

    d3.transition(g.select('.nv-context .nv-y.nv-axis'))
      .call(y2Axis);

    g.select('.nv-context .nv-x.nv-axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + y2.range()[0] + ')');
```

Should work, but not fully tested.